# How do I install "SQL Server" ODBC Driver?

Tags: sql-server, installation

I Have "SQL Native Client", but not "SQL Server" ODBC driver. I have SQL 2005 installed on my machine.

Tried to fix by installing SQL Server client tools.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

I'm running Windows XP Pro.

Answer (score 3):

Found this [Microsoft download](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6C050FE3-C795-4B7D-B037-185D0506396C&displaylang=en). It says it provides the SQL Server ODBC driver.

Edit:
Here's the SP1 download: [Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?familyid=78CAC895-EFC2-4F8E-A9E0-3A1AFBD5922E&displaylang=en).

Comment: I get an error... MDAC 2.8 RTM - MDAC 2.8 RTM is incompatible with this version of Windows. All of its features are currently part of Windows.

Comment: So, just to give a reason, if you >= XP SP2, it already has MDAC 2.8. 

Thanks for the info, it lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I found an [article](http://www.macropool.com/en/download/mdac_xp_sp2.html) on repairing MDAC.

Here is the short

1. In Windows Explorer, open the c:\Windows\Inf folder.

Note If you cannot see the c:\Windows\Inf folder, follow these steps:

a. On the desktop, double-click My Computer, and then on the Tools menu, click Folder Options.

b.    Click the View tab.

c.    Under Advanced settings, select the Show hidden files and folders check box.

d.    Clear the Hide extensions for known file types check box.

e.    Click OK.

2. In the C:\Windows\Inf folder, right-click the Mdac.inf file, and then click Install.

...

Answer (score -1):

You can also try the OpenLink ODBC Drivers for SQL Server. These support older and newer versions of SQL Server (from 4.2 up to very latest release).

See: http://uda.openlinksw.com/

Answer (score -1):

The Easysoft SQL Server ODBC Driver support both old and new versions of SQLServer
http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-sql-server-driver/index.html